# Simple TimeZones

Tags: c#, .net

I need to send out emails based on a timestamp. But the timestamp must be what the user expects it to be.

The timestamp is set by the user submitting an object.

E.g

Al from L.A in the U.S saves an object with a timestamp of '3/30/2015 10:00:00AM'.

Lars from Berlin in Germany saves an object with the timestamp of '4/15/2015 11:00:00PM'.

The system that looks at these objects and later sends out emails is based in a GMT+1 timezone.

My thought, to keep it super simple, is to add or subtract the difference in the timezone hours, based on where the object is from (timezone).

So in Al's example the system would subtract 9 hours (GMT+1 difference) but in Lars' example the system would keep the date, since Germany is also GMT+1.

Wouldn't that be an ok soultion ?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, but if you're suggesting storing all timestamps in GMT then converting "on the fly" when communicating with users, that's a very good idea.

Comment: What time do you use for [Arizona](http://gmttimedate.com/country1/files/Arizona%20Time%20Zones.jpg)?

Comment: @MichaelT Hey! No picking on Arizona! :-) Just because most of us have decided to forego fiddling with our clocks twice each year...

Comment: @EricKing I feel sorry for the people doing the schedule at Hoover Dam. Half the people work in Nevada (Pacific, Daylight Savings), the other half work in Arizona (Mountain, No Daylight Savings).  For part of the year, the staff is 1h out of sync... and for part of the year, the staff is 2h out of sync.

Comment: @MichaelT True, very true. Nevada's system certainly _is_ wacky, and can cause confusion. I see your point.

Comment: Time zones do not all have an integer offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web server is saving the data, not the user, so it doesn't matter what the user's time is.  The object should be saved with a timestamp in GMT (universal) time format.  Save the user's GMT timezone offset, Then add that offset to the timestamp (which is in UTC) to present to the user, his own local time.

For example, since I'm in CA, my UTCTimeZoneOffset would be -8.  Add -8 to 21:00UTC and for me, it's 13:00PST.

Comment: This is what came to me as well. Since I know the users timezone I can just save the time in GMT and add the offset when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Not so much. Maybe.

The problem is that if Al from LA marks something with 1/1/2015 10AM and 7/1/2015 10AM, those will be *different* offsets from GMT.

"What the user expects it to be" can get really dicey given our overly complex way of measuring times. Where at all possible, work using UTC (which may or may not be different from GMT depending on your precision needs) and translate to local time as close to display to the user as possible.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Different how ?

Comment: @frostings - http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/los-angeles

Comment: @frostings Different because January is Pacific Standard Time (UTC-8) and July is Pacific Daylight Time (UTC-7).